# Proper Subset function in Python

Tags: python, set

I want a function that will say if a subset is proper. So if they are identical it will return True, if they aren't then False. I have a very simple design but it doesn't account for the set's properties, which is if there are duplicates in the set it will delete them. It will also be identifical if one set is IN the other set. 
Here's my code:

```
def proper_subset(S,T):
  if S == T:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Here's some test cases on what it does and what it SHOULD do:

```
#What it does
S = {1,2}
T = {1,2,3}
proper_subset(S,T)
>>> False

#What it should do
S = {1,2}
T = {1,2,3}
proper_subset(S,T)
>>> True
```

Please help!

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: You need to analyze this assignment: what are the functional properties of a proper subset?  How do you represent those in the Python set capabilities?

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Comment: You can just use `<` for this.

Comment: The set type [already provides this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset). Why are you trying to implement this yourself? If it is an assignment, what are your restrictions?

Comment: "my code doesn't work"?  Your code doesn't address the assignment at all; hence my earlier comments.  Your posted code checks for set equality; for any subset, proper or not, it returns the wrong result.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the `issubset` method returns true for a given set and itself. Interestingly on that same docs page you can find the < comparator listed as "proper subset".

Comment: @kpie The question notes that True is the desired result when both sets are identical. That of course conflicts with the desired result being „proper subset“ as well. No matter what behavior the OP *actually* desires, the set type provides it. Writing a custom function is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In python the set entity supports addition and subtraction. So you can just check the lengths of the subtraction operations.

```
def properSubset(S,T):
    return len(S-T)==0 and len(T-S)>0
```

Also as the comments mention you can just use '<'

```
def properSubset(S,T):
    return S<T
```

Comment: There is no need to use ˋlenˋ to check for empty / not-empty. Also, set.__lt__ can just be aliased to a different name, a wrapper function is unnecessary.